# Layout issue with ios7 iphone5 screen but working fine in iphone5 and ios8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7.1, xcode6.1, ios8.1

Iam new to ios development,

In my application i designed UI through storyboard. Its looking good when i am using iphone5 with ios 8.1 but with iphone5 and ios 7.1 having some spaces top and bottom of screen.

check this images , what could be the problem?

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

iPhone 5 with ios 7.1[image]

iphone5 with ios 8.1[image]

Comment: do you have Default-568@2x.png image? it looks like iOS 7 is taking iphone 4 size storyboard and it occurs bcz of no default image for iphone 5s.

Comment: @Sudha: please do not add `code ticks` to any random phrase resembling code. Note that all of your accepted edits that only do this are in progress of being rolled back to the previous format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo.. I was able to resolve it.

To resolve the issue, follow the below steps:

1. Navigate to project settings
2. Under "App Icons and Launch Images" click on "Use Asset Catalog"
3. Select "Migrate" on the popup that appears.

Its working fine for me.

Comment: That is irrelevant. Also never trust your simulator